# Lists within lists

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I'm making a ArrayList of Linked Lists to hold some Entry's for a phone book. Everyone with a surname beginning with A goes in the first list, B goes in the second list etc. Im trying to make the add method for an Entry to go in the list of lists. But I'm getting IndexOutOfBounds exceptions. Here is my addEntry method.

```
List<LinkedList<Entry>> phoneBook = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Entry>>(26);

public void addEntry(String surname, String initial, String phoneNumber) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(surname);
    String word = sc.next();
    word = word.toUpperCase();
    char ch = word.charAt(0);
    int i = ch;
    i -= 65; 
    phoneBook.get(i).add(new Entry(surname, initial, phoneNumber));
}
```

So I'm trying to look at the first letter of the surname, if its A, go to element(0) which is another linked list, and then add the Entry there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid the `IndexOutOfBounds` you need to ensure that your outer list is initialized with 26 entries.

The code that you use below does not work:

```
List<LinkedList<Entry>> phoneBook = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Entry>>(26);
```

It gives `phoneBook` a capacity of 26, but its size remains zero. You need to add 26 linked lists to `phoneBook`. You can do it like this:

```
List<LinkedList<Entry>> phoneBook = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Entry>>(26);
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 26 ; i++) {
        phoneBook.add(new LinkedList<Entry>());
    }
}
```

You also need to check that `i` is within these bounds, otherwise weird last names that start in letters other than the 26 letters of the Latin alphabet would cause your program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
LinkedList<Entry> tmp = phoneBook.get(i);
if (tmp == null) tmp = new LinkedList<Entry>();
tmp.add(new Entry(surname, initial, phoneNumber));
phoneBook.set(i, tmp);
```